# How can i save my markers added manually to google maps v2 when exiting the app or navigating to different activity?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a map which users can add different markers, but the problem is that when the markers have been added and the users leaves the app or navigates away from the map to a new activity and back to map the markers added have disappeared.  I am relatively new to android app development,  so could some one please assist me?

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_googlemaps);
 }

@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

 }

@Override
    public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
try {
        initilizeMap();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
 private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment)  getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! aren't able to create your map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
    public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    initilizeMap();

    if (googleMap!=null){
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(My Point)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.my_point_marker)));

}
CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(
         new LatLng(xx.xxxxxxx,xx.xxxxxxzoom(9).bearing(0).build();

 googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
 googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
 googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
 googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
 googleMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
 googleMap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);
 googleMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

 }

MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
         .position(theLastPlaceThatTheUserLongClicked)
         .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
         .fromBitmap(bitmap));
          haspMap.put(markerOptions, your_data);
         googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
   }
 }
```

Thank you in advance!

**Update**

I have found this and think that this might help?

```
 ...........
  WeakHashMap <Marker, Object> haspMap = new WeakHashMap <Marker, Object>();
 ..........

  MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
             .position(point)
             .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
             .fromBitmap(bitmap));
              haspMap.put(markerOptions, your_data);
             googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        }
```

I understand the use of the WeakHashMap and then the haspMap,  but not quite sure what goes by `your_data`.  I couldn't find an explanation for that?

Comment: You got that mixed up. A HashMap stores Objects that are referenced by keys. The first Object is your key (typically a String) and the second Object is your_data == your Marker object. You'll have to change WeakHashMap <Marker, Object> to WeakHashMap <String, Marker> or WeakHashMap <Integer, Marker> if you want to use the Map like a List.

Answer (score 1):

Store all the latlng value in list ,whenever user click on map..and on onResume() traverse the complete list and set the stored latlng in map ..